# Intersection of two heterogeneous list in C#

Tags: c#, linq, list, filter

I would like to get the intersection of two lists: a list of GameObject's, and a list of Realproperty's. And get this result inside a new list which would be of type List< Lot >. Lot being a member of GameObject

```
class GameObject
{
    public string m_lotName;
    public Lot m_lot;
    //other members
}

class Lot
{
    public string m_lotName;
    //other members
}

class RealProperty
{
    public string m_name;
    //other members
}

List<GameObject> allLots = getAllLots();
List<RealProperty> soldRealProperties = getSoldRealProperties();
```

I would like to get a *List< Lot >* which would be the result of: a *List< GameObject >* filtered by a *List< RealProperty >* where for each gameobject of *List< GameObject >* we test if *gameobject.m_lot.m_lotName* is present inside the *List< RealProperty > elements*.

It seems that LINQ makes it possible

I tried something like this:

```
List<Lot> soldLots = allLots
            .Select(a => a.GetComponent<Lot>().m_lotName)
            .Where(u => allLots
                       .Select(l => l.m_lot.m_lotName)
                       .Intersect(soldRealProperties
                           .Select(l2 => l2.m_name))
                           );
```

But I get a lot of errors, like these one:

```
Type `string' does not contain a definition for `m_name' and no extension method `m_name' of type `string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Type `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' does not contain a member `Contains' and the best extension method overload `System.Linq.Queryable.Contains<object>(this System.Linq.IQueryable<object>, object)' has some invalid arguments
Extension method instance type `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' cannot be converted to `System.Linq.IQueryable<object>'
```

Is there an easy way to get the intersection of two heterogeneous lists?

Comment: You should really stop using `m_` prefix for your property names, makes it horribly unreadable.

Comment: You've selected out `LotID` in your first `Select`, it's no longer a list of your `Lot` type, it's a list of whatever the type of `LotID` is (presumably string).

Comment: @DavidG: What would be a good convention for you? mName ?

Comment: Would there be something missing for you if it were simply "Name"? That way you would have Lot.Name

Comment: @Sean: I've made a typo. Thanx for the remark. I've just corrected it by switched LotID into m_lotName

Comment: @matt There's lot of options and company/personal preference, but [Microsoft guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/ms229045(v=vs.100).aspx) are a good place to start

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Enumerable.Join`:

```
var intersecting = from game in allLots
                   join realProp in soldRealProperties
                   on game.m_lotName equals realProp.m_name
                   select game.m_lot;
List<Lot> soldLots = intersecting.ToList();
```

Comment: Thanx Tim for your answer.
Indeed the new List<Lot> needs Lot that are exact copies of what they are in game.m_lot. 
Does " new Lot { m_lotName = game.m_lotName }" create new Lot's with just their name initialized, or does it create a copy of the lot members in List<GameObject> ?

Comment: @matt: it creates new `Lot` instances with the same name. I haven't seen that `GameObject` has a porperty of type `Lot`. Then you can use `select game.m_lot` instead. Note that this property is lower-case `lot`, is that a typo?

Comment: thanx Tim. Yes that's a typo, I've just changed it. I will try your solution right now